# How to translate four particles GHZ states into X basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hilbert-space

Now I have four particles GHZ states in Z basis, i.e.|0000>+|1111>
Now I wang to know how to write it in the X basis（|+>,|->）?
Is there a simple way for multiparty particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four-qubit GHZ state in the X basis is
$$\begin{split}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\big(&|++++\rangle+|--++\rangle+|-+-+\rangle+|-++-\rangle+\\&|+--+\rangle+|+-+-\rangle+|++--\rangle+|----\rangle\big)\end{split}.$$
The imporatant feature is that it is a superposition of all X basis states with **even** number of "$-$" ($X=-1$ spins). In general, for multiple qubits the state can be expressed as
$$\sum_{\{{X_i}=\pm\}}\Big(1+\prod_{i}X_i\Big)\otimes_{i}|X_i\rangle.$$

Comment: how to determine the - or +？ for instance, how to determine is |++++>+|--++>...... instead of  |++++>-|--++>? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Xiang.G Because the GHZ state is an eigenstate of the string operator XXXX (i.e. four X operators, each on a site, product together). Then in the X basis, when XXXX acts on the basis state, the basis state remains unchanged but will let out a sign factor which is determined by the parity of the number of "$-$" spins in the basis. But the number of "$-$" spin is always even, so the sign factor is always positive.